# Magento 1.9.3.7 Warning tax discount configuration might result in different discounts than a customer might expect

Tags: magento-1.9, tax

The following configuration has been applied. What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What if you set "apply customer tax" `after discount`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issue with discount settings.If it is not configured properly, it will show warning message. Discount setting should be:

[image]

As per official document from [Magento](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/tax/warning-messages.html), You need to change setting:

form

`Apply Customer Tax -> Before Discount`

to

`Apply Customer Tax -> After Discount`

Correct Setting will be:

[image]

**Reference:** https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/tax/warning-messages.html